# Data Interoperability FME - Python Exception <KeyError>: u'hasZ'

Tags: feature-service, arcgis-portal, fme-form

I have an issue with data interoperability using a feature service as a reader and a writer.

I'm reading from a feature service a table and using it to enrich it with data from an Access database and send back the updated version.

**Two readers**:

-ArcGIS Portal - Feature Service "A"

-Access Database

**One Writer**

-ArcGIS Portal - Feature Service "A"

I receive an error as follows:

> Consider using coordinate system 'EPSG:31700' instead of '_EPSG:31700_0'
>
> ArcGIS Portal Feature Service Writer: Getting item with ID '3a50c62127f8473fa7feb8be1be0c483'
>
> ArcGIS Portal Feature Service Writer: Requesting metadata for Feature Service at 'http://--------------.ro/server/rest/services/Hosted/Cornu_test/FeatureServer'
>
> ArcGIS Portal Feature Service Writer: Getting item with ID '3a50c62127f8473fa7feb8be1be0c483'
>
> ArcGIS Portal Feature Service Writer: Requesting metadata for Feature Service at 'http://--------------.ro/server/rest/services/Hosted/Cornu_test/FeatureServer'
>   ArcGIS Portal Feature Service Writer: Found layer/table 'Person' with ID 3 for feature type 'Person'
>
> ArcGIS Portal Feature Service Writer: Requesting metadata for layer/table 3 of Feature Service at 'http://--------------.ro/server/rest/services/Hosted/Cornu_test/FeatureServer'
>
> **Python Exception : u'hasZ'**
>
> A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
>
> A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details

Comment: Which version of FME/ArcGIS are you using? I do see an example of the Python Exception : u'hasZ' error but it appears fixed in FME2016. Of course, this could easily be a different issue. I think - given that I can't find any useful info - it would be best to ask your official support contacts for help. If this is the Data Interop extension then I believe your support request should go through Esri. If it's plain FME (even if you have Interop too) then you should contact your local FME reseller, or the main Safe Software support team (www.safe.com/support) depending where you purchased from.